# TypeError: _ffmpeg_ffmpeg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, node.js, flask, ffmpeg, speech-recognition

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

import \* as FFmpeg from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg";

const AudioRecorders = ({ onAudioRecorded }) =\> {
const \[permission, setPermission\] = useState(false);
const \[stream, setStream\] = useState(null);
const mimeType = "video/webm";
const mediaRecorder = useRef(null);
const \[recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus\] = useState("inactive");
const \[audioChunks, setAudioChunks\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[audio, setAudio\] = useState(null);

const ffmpeg = useRef(null);

const createFFmpeg = async ({ log = false }) =\> {
// here I am facing the error
const ffmpegInstance = new FFmpeg({ log });
await ffmpegInstance.load();
return ffmpegInstance;
};

const convertWebmToWav = async (webmBlob) =\> {
if (!ffmpeg.current) {
ffmpeg.current = await createFFmpeg({ log: false });
}

    const inputName = "input.webm";
    const outputName = "output.wav";
    
    ffmpeg.current.FS("writeFile", inputName, await webmBlob.arrayBuffer());
    await ffmpeg.current.run("-i", inputName, outputName);
    
    const outputData = ffmpeg.current.FS("readFile", outputName);
    const outputBlob = new Blob([outputData.buffer], { type: "audio/wav" });
    
    return outputBlob;

};

const getMicrophonePermission = async () =\> {
if ("MediaRecorder" in window) {
try {
const streamData = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
audio: true,
video: false,
});
setPermission(true);
setStream(streamData);
} catch (err) {
alert(err.message);
}
} else {
alert("The MediaRecorder API is not supported in your browser.");
}
};

const startRecording = async () =\> {
setRecordingStatus("recording");
//create new Media recorder instance using the stream
const media = new MediaRecorder(stream, { type: mimeType });
//set the MediaRecorder instance to the mediaRecorder ref
mediaRecorder.current = media;
//invokes the start method to start the recording process
mediaRecorder.current.start();
let localAudioChunks = \[\];
mediaRecorder.current.ondataavailable = (event) =\> {
if (typeof event.data === "undefined") return;
if (event.data.size === 0) return;
localAudioChunks.push(event.data);
};
setAudioChunks(localAudioChunks);
};

const stopRecording = () =\> {
setRecordingStatus("inactive");
//stops the recording instance
mediaRecorder.current.stop();
mediaRecorder.current.onstop = async () =\> {
//creates a blob file from the audiochunks data
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: mimeType });
// creates a playable URL from the blob file.
const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
// converts the WebM blob to a WAV blob.
const newBlob = await convertWebmToWav(audioBlob);
await onAudioRecorded(newBlob);
setAudio(audioUrl);
setAudioChunks(\[\]);
};
};

return (
\<div\>
<h2>Audio Recorder</h2>
\<main\>
\<div className="audio-controls"\>
{!permission ? (
\<button onClick={getMicrophonePermission} type="button"\>
Get Microphone
\</button\>
) : null}
{permission && recordingStatus === "inactive" ? (
\<button onClick={startRecording} type="button"\>
Start Recording
\</button\>
) : null}
{recordingStatus === "recording" ? (
\<button onClick={stopRecording} type="button"\>
Stop Recording
\</button\>
) : null}
{audio ? (
\<div className="audio-container"\>
\<audio src={audio} controls\>\</audio\>
<a>
Download Recording
</a>
\</div\>
) : null}
\</div\>
\</main\>
\</div\>
);
};
export default AudioRecorders;

\`
```

ERROR
*ffmpeg_ffmpeg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_ is not a constructor
TypeError: *ffmpeg_ffmpeg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_ is not a constructor
at createFFmpeg (http://localhost:3000/main.48220156e0c620f1acd0.hot-update.js:41:28)
at convertWebmToWav (http://localhost:3000/main.48220156e0c620f1acd0.hot-update.js:49:30)
at mediaRecorder.current.onstop (http://localhost:3000/main.48220156e0c620f1acd0.hot-update.js:109:29)`

```
I am trying to record the voice in audio/wav formate but its recording in video/webm formate not because of \<const mimeType = "video/webm"\>. Whatever the mimeType I am giving its showing the file type video/webm on "https://www.checkfiletype.com/". I am recording it for the speech_recognition used in flask backend which is accepting only audio/wav.
So in frontend I have written a function "convertWebmToWav " which is giving me the error :
Uncaught runtime errors:
```